# Sending array from android to php. $_POST shows Array() string

Tags: php, android, arrays

Call from android is as follows

```
CallWebServiceTask task = new CallWebServiceTask(6, this,
                "Fetching Data From Server");
        int key = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < localIds.size(); i++) {
           key = localIds.keyAt(i);
           // get the object by the key.
           task.addNameValuePair("ids", ""+key);
        }

        task.execute(url);
```

This one will add a list of ids to the key `ids`.

On my php when I do, `print_r($_POST);` it returns just `Array()` as a string.

How, do I extract the array values in php in an array. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just encode your array as a `JSONArray` and post it to your `PHP` server, much easier to work with this way.

```
CallWebServiceTask task = new CallWebServiceTask(6, this,
                "Fetching Data From Server");
task.addNameValuePair("ids", new JSONArray(localIds));
task.execute(url);
```

Comment: How exactly? Shall I not use name value pair?

Comment: Yes use it , get rid of the loop because you are overwriting the post keys

Comment: So you want me to send {id1 : 1, id2 : 2, id3 : 3} instead of {ids : 1,2,3}?

Comment: depends or like this `{ "ids" : [ 1, 2, 3] }` , but most importantly send it as JSON

Comment: But the way, I've done it, it should go as a json right? And the json should look exactly like ^the one mentioned in your comment. Or am I getting something wrong here.

Comment: no the way you are doing is putting a java object, instead of primitive data such as int, strings, boolean. this is why you see `Array` in your dump. `NameValuePair` dont take arrays. In my comment it is just an example, you can format it like you wanrt

Comment: @Kraken Does it make sense ? or you need a sample code ? see my edit

Answer (score 0):

```
CallWebServiceTask task = new CallWebServiceTask(6, this,
                "Fetching Data From Server");
        int key = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < localIds.size(); i++) {
           key = localIds.keyAt(i);
           // get the object by the key.
           task.addNameValuePair("ids"+i, ""+key);
        }

        task.execute(url);
```